# LaTeX rollback - unexpected behavior

Tags: latex-base

Typesetting this mwe

```
\RequirePackage[2015/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

I expect it to be indicated the LaTeX version 2015/01/01 into the log file. Instead I read

```
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
```

that is the latest version preloaded in TeXLive 2023.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Unrelated to the question about the banner but I really wouldn't expect anything to work if you roll back that far. You revert most format changes but all the surrounding packages you have from ctan are current 2024 versions that probably do not work on that old format.

Comment: Yes, of course... I simply copied the date used in the `latexrelease` package documentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latex banner comes from `\everyjob` so is issued before the rollback starts rolling.

Note that `\RequirePackage[2015/01/01]{latexrelease}` is not some magic line like the `%&lualatex` line that changes the format in some implementations. It is simply a normal package code that loads some code to emulate older releases. The format that loads initially is a standard current latex.